# How to sort a list of dictionaries by 2 keys, one of which is based on an arbitrary list

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I'm using python.
How do I sort the list of dictionaries below first by 'day' then by 'job'.
The sort on 'job' needs to be based on priority_list (not alphabetically):

```
priority_list= ['c','a','b']

my_list_of_dicts = [
{'day':5,'job':'c','irrelevant_key':'more stuff'},
{'day':1,'job':'a','irrelevant_key':'stuff'},
{'day':5,'job':'b','irrelevant_key':'more stuff'},
{'day':1,'job':'b','irrelevant_key':'other stuff'}
]
```

result of sorting should be:

```
[{'day':1,'job':'a','irrelevant_key':'stuff'},
{'day':1,'job':'b','irrelevant_key':'other stuff'},
{'day':5,'job':'c','irrelevant_key':'more stuff'},
{'day':5,'job':'b','irrelevant_key':'more stuff'}]
```

Thanks very much,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my_list_of_dicts.sort(key=lambda x: (x['day'], priority_list.index(x['job'])))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def key(d):
    return d['day'], priority_list.index(d['job'])

sorted(my_list_of_dicts, key=key)
```

Answer (score 2):

For a very small list, such as your example, the answers using `list.index()` will work fine.

However, if the list is large, it would be worth the time to build a `dict` out of the `priority_list`.  `dict` lookups are O(1), while `list` lookups are O(N).

```
priority_dict = dict((x, i) for i, x in enumerate(priority_list))

def key_day_priority(d):
    return d['day'], priority_dict[d['job']]

my_list_of_dicts.sort(key=key_day_priority)
```